# Using This with selector in Javascript "Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, this, selector

I am trying to use This and find some elements that are further down in the DOM

The HTML goes like this

```
<div class="photovignette">
        <h2><span>E</span>xplorascape</h2>
        <div class="text">
            <svg>
                <defs>
                    <mask id="maskexplora" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <rect class="alpha" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
                        <text class="title" x="50%" y="10%" dy="1.58em">Explorascape</text>
                    </mask>
                </defs>
                <rect class="baseexplora" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is that for a specific ".photovignette" I'd like to apply an animation to the ".alpha" inside the  like this :

```
    $(".photovignette").mouseover(function () {
         anime({
             targets: this.document.getElementsByClassName("alpha"),
             scale: {
                 value: 0.7,
                 duration: 500,
                 easing: 'easeOutElastic'
             },
             loop: false,
         });
```

if I use This only, it works. But when I try to find the "alpha" it gives me this error : "Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined"

How to deal with that?

Comment: `this` is a DOM element and it doesn't have `document` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find a descendant element of the hovered element you can use the `.querySelector` method:

```
this.querySelector(".alpha")
```

In jQuery:

```
// `.get(index)` extracts a DOM element from the collection
$(this).find('.alpha').get(0)
```

If the `targets` should be a collection of DOM elements, then you can use the `.querySelectorAll` method:

```
this.querySelectorAll(".alpha")
```

In jQuery:

```
$(this).find('.alpha').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :-

```
$(".photovignette").mouseover(function () {
         anime({
             targets: $(this).find('.alpha'),
             scale: {
                 value: 0.7,
                 duration: 500,
                 easing: 'easeOutElastic'
             },
             loop: false,
         });
```

Comment: The problem is that I have multiple photovignette, and I would like to apply the animation only to the alpha that goes with it.
And the animation library I'm using doesn't allow jquery selectors unfortunately...

Comment: you could assign id to that particular element or pass event as param and use that to find assoicated alpha. event.find('.alpha').

Comment: Updated my fiddle using this event..It's working fine.